# sscanf using @ as delimeter

Tags: c, scanf

Using '@' as delimeter in sscanf, i am not getting the expected result.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char buf[512], scan_buf1[512], scan_buf2[512];
        sprintf(buf, "abc@def");
        sscanf(buf, "%s@%s", scan_buf1, scan_buf2);
        printf("Scanned buffer1 - %s scan buffer2 - %s\n", scan_buf1, scan_buf2);
}

Expected op:
Scanned buffer1 - abc scan buffer2 - def

Actual op:
Scanned buffer1 - abc@def scan buffer2 -
```

Should I use some special syntax for "@" ? I could not see anything for it in man page.

Comment: The problem isn't particular to the at (`@`) symbol. It would happen with anything because `scanf` for `%s` reads a whole string. There is then no string left to read to match `@%s` or anything else in the format string.

Comment: `sscanf()` expects spaces as delimiters. But you can use `strtok()` to parse this line.

Comment: try `"%[^@]@%s"`or use `strchr(buf, '@')` and split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that the `"%s"` format reads

> a sequence of non-whitespace characters

That means the `"%s"` will read characters until it reaches a white-space. Since you don't have a white-space in your input it will read all into the first string.

You can solve this by using the `"%["` format:

```
sscanf(buf, "%[^@]@%s", scan_buf1, scan_buf2);
```

Comment: Hi, It is working. Thank you. BDW is strtok as suggested in one of the comments, a better option here?

Comment: @Manty You need more code to work with [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), so I would recommend using `sscanf` in your case.

Comment: Interesting answer did not suggest `"%[^@]@%[^@]"` for symmetry nor did it advise checking the `sscanf()` return value.